# What the meaning of package version number with word 'really' in the middle?

Tags: apt, package-management, versions

Command `apt-cache show postgresql` will listed this information in my machine (Saucy Salamander 13.10):

```
$ apt-cache show postgresql
Package: postgresql
Priority: optional
Section: database
Installed-Size: 69
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian PostgreSQL Maintainers <pkg-postgresql-public@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: postgresql-common (148)
Version: 9.3+146really9.1+148
Depends: postgresql-9.1
```

It says postgresql package version `9.3+146really9.1+148`. What the meaning of `really` here?

- is this version 9.1 but listed as 9.3?
- or this is version 9.1 with patch back-ported from 9.3?
- or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually 9.1. Saucy seems to be pulling postgresql* packages from Debian's unstable dist, where because of some version dependencies they had to make the 9.1 branch look like 9.3 to the package manager until 9.3 graduates from their experimental to their unstable distro.

See here: 
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=707675

Especially the changelog bit reading:

```
   * debian/supported-versions: Don't explicitly support 9.3 for
     testing/unstable yet, it is still in experimental. (Closes: #707675)
   * debian/rules: Hack the version number of the metapackages to be
     9.3+142really9.1-..., so that they are bigger than the previous botched
     versions. This needs to stay until 9.3 actually goes into unstable.
```

Comment: one example of dependency hell... :D thanks for tracking back into exact bug information.